# Duplicate analysis using conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do some analysis of the duplicates prior to drop all of them and keep the first or the last result. I want to check the quality of the duplicates in order to keep one or remove both value.

I want to put some conditions:

If pIC50 of the duplicates have a difference lower than 0.2 in the pIC50 column, I want to keep one and the the value as a mean. If it is higher than that, drop both rows.

```py
hHDAC6_dup = pd.DataFrame(columns=["molecule_chembl_id", "pIC50"], data=[["CHEMBL407959", 6.468521], ["CHEMBL98", 6.795880], ["CHEMBL98", 7.721246], ["CHEMBL98", 7.75]])

if (hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[1] == hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[2]) and (abs(hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] - hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2]) > 0.2):
    hHDAC6_dup.drop([1, 2], axis=0, inplace=True)
elif (hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[1] == hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[2]) and (abs(hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] - hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2]) <= 0.2):
    hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] = (hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] + hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2])/2 
    hHDAC6_dup.drop(2, axis=0, inplace=True)
else:
    pass
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-b55b2493278b> in <module>
----> 1 if (hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[1] == hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[2]) and (abs(hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] - hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2]) > 0.2):
      2     hHDAC6_dup.drop([1, 2], axis=0, inplace=True)
      3 elif (hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[1] == hHDAC6_dup.molecule_chembl_id[2]) and (abs(hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] - hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2]) <= 0.2):
      4     hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] = (hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[1] + hHDAC6_dup.pIC50[2])/2
      5     hHDAC6_dup.drop(2, axis=0, inplace=True)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 1
```

I would need to iterate to do this analysis in the whole df.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error message you have shown shows a different code from what you provided on your example. Also, could you provide a minimal reproducible example? It is not clear what the contents of `hHDAC6_dup` are.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just figured out that I took from other output:

Comment: Dear nonDucor, the hHDAC6_dup is the df that I put 3 row, just that. The whole df contains 860 rows.

Comment: I tested your code with the data you provided and it works. By the way, a minimum reproducible example should include the definition of the input variables, so I used `hHDAC6_dup = pd.DataFrame(columns=["molecule_chembl_id", "pIC50"], data=[["CHEMBL407959", 6.468521], ["CHEMBL98", 6.795880], ["CHEMBL98", 7.721246]])`  as input. Since I can't reproduce the error, my only guess is that your in-place changing of the data frame is creating an error if you execute the code twice without reconstructing the variable.

Comment: Thank you nonDucor!!! I will try to check this!

Comment: Another part of your question is not clear: "After, I would need to iterate along the columns as well." Do you mean rows? And, if you mean rows, are you assured to have only single pairs of duplicated values or would you have larger groups (e.g. 3 or 4 rows with values for `CHEMBL98`)? In any case, you should have a look in [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Comment: Yes, I mean the rows. There are some duplicates with more than 1 pair.

Comment: And what do you want to do with a duplicate that has 3 entries? Drop all if each is more than 0.2 away from the group mean?

Comment: Yes! It would be perfect!

Comment: So, please edit your question so it states all of this clearly. The problem you are stating after all these comments is completely different from what is in your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your own aggregation function, you can use `groupby` to do this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def mean_if_close(seq, tolerance=0.2):
    span = np.max(seq) - np.min(seq)
    if span <= tolerance:
        return np.mean(seq)
    return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
                   'value': [1.5, 3, 3.3, 4.1, 4.15, 4.2]})

df.groupby('id').agg(mean_if_close).dropna()
```

```
    value
id  
a   1.50
c   4.15
```